# How to add attributes to a tag on the basis of child element tag's attribute in xslt

Tags: html, xml, attributes, xslt-1.0

I need to Convert all tags with the following property to codeblock tag

```
    <span style="font-family:courier new,courier,monospace;">
    <span class="mt-font-courier-new">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a specific template to handle that case:

```
<xsl:apply templates="*" />

<xsl:template match="span[contains(@style, 'courier')]|span[contains(@style, 'courier')]|span[contains(@class, 'courier')]">
    <codeblock>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </codeblock>
</xsl:template>
```

You can of course either define the selector with exact values, or use fuzzy matching via contains to get those tags.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is working fine..Thanks for your response :)

By using this code:

```
<xsl:template match="span[contains(@style, 'font-family:courier new,courier,monospace;')]|span[contains(@class, 'mt-font-courier-new')]">
    <codeblock>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </codeblock>
</xsl:template>
```